SQL: multiply values for each rows for column "price"
I have a Prestashop website where I need to increase price for each products and specifically in table "products" I need to multiply column "price" (for each rows that contain already values) for 1.22 (I need to add Italian VAT on this way).
I think that via SQL is the best way without download a csv file, edit via spreadsheet and than re-import.
Someone can show me which SQL command I should use?
Thanks a lot!

Which dbms you are using?

No need to UNLOAD and LOAD, simply use UPDATE to update your table.

Something like UPDATE tablename SET price = price * 1.22.

this command UPDATE tablename SET price = price * 1.22 sounds good, it will update all rows from that table name?

This is likely no good idea. You usually don't save "final prices" and escpecially don't override "base prices". What's the purpose of that? Leave the price in the product table as it is. Create a table vats and a column vat_id in the product table. Then save the vat with its percentage in the vat table and assign the vat's id to the vat_id column in the product table. Finally, calculcate the price of the product if it is sold with this vat. Do the same for further price modifications like discounts.

Or to further improve your DB structure, even create a table transactions, trans_vats or something similar because a product can be sold with different vats.

You can use the following SQL code to update the prices:
If you want to update the existing price by applying the 22% Italian VAT:
UPDATE products SET price = price * 1.22
    WHERE price > 0;

Alternatively, if you want to keep the original price and add a new column to store the price with Italian VAT:
ALTER TABLE products ADD COLUMN price_with_Italian_VAT DECIMAL(10, 2) AFTER price;

UPDATE products SET price_with_Italian_VAT = price * 1.22
    WHERE price > 0;

Here are some additional important notes:

Check Table Prefix and Column Names: Ensure that you use the correct
table prefix and column names in the queries.
Data Backup: Always back up your database before performing updates.
This ensures you can recover the original values if needed.
Decimal Precision: The DECIMAL(10, 2) data type is commonly used for
monetary values to ensure that prices are stored with two decimal
places. Double-check that the price_with_Italian_VAT column is
defined with the appropriate data type.


Why the WHERE clause?

The WHERE clause in an SQL query is used to filter out rows where the price is zero, ensuring that no zero values are included in the calculation and preventing multiplication by zero

What's the problem to multiply zero by anything? Why do you want to exclude negative prices?

Apologies for my earlier response—I mistakenly mentioned that multiplying by zero would cause an error; I was actually thinking about division, not multiplication. However, using the WHERE clause can definitely improve performance.

I believe you could use something as simple as
UPDATE YourTable SET price = price * 1.22 

or
UPDATE YourTable SET price = price * YourColumn

if you have a field with the price value

Note tables don't have fields, but columns.
